# Generate code from Business Process Model and Notation (BPMN) with androMDA

Tags: uml, bpmn, mda, andromda

I know that AndroMDA generate code from UML model,

my question is:
it is possible to generate code from BPMN model (Business Process Model and Notation) with androMDA (i.e create a new cartridge which support BPMN)?

Comment: Don't try code generation, try [Activiti](www.activiti.org). It runs the BPMN with all kinds of advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is not to generate code for BPMN model, but interpret it, Take a look on [jBPM cartrige](http://www.andromda.org/andromda-cartridges/andromda-jbpm-cartridge/index.html) for AndroMDA.